# computing quotient ideals efficiently over a polynomial ring: (I:J) when J has many generators?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Can someone guide me to a reference where an algorithm for computing I:J where
J has many generators is discussed? I know the method of using one generator at a time and then taking intersections. I would prefer a method that uses all generators simultaneously which I am hoping will be more efficient.

Thanks.